# Inverse of matrix product.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am trying to generally find the inverse of a matrix which is a sum of two matrices. Specifically, want to find $A^{-1}$ when I have

$A = DSD + I$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, $S$ is an invertible positive semi-definite matrix, and $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity. Is there any way to do this generally?

Comment: @markvs then $S$ is not PSD.

Comment: Are you okay with infinite sums? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series